# How to pass json data from one component to another using functions in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How can I pass data from one component to another?

Like for instance if someone clicks forget the password, it prompts him to enter an email, and then it sends a post request to confirm either the user exists or not.
If the user does exist, it sends back the security question as a response, and then it should take the user to another screen along with the security question we got from the prev component and display that there and ask the user to answer the question for it.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import ForgetPassword from './ForgetPassword';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const VerifyUser = ({ setAuth }) => {
  let [parseData, setParseData] = useState('');
  // let [con1, setcon1] = useState(false);

  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    email: '',
  });

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setInputs({ ...inputs, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const onSubmitForm = async (e) => {
    try {
      e.preventDefault();
      const body = { email };
      const bodyFile = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
      };
      const response = await fetch(
        'http://localhost:5000/forgetpassword/verifyuser',
        bodyFile
      );
      const parseRes = await response.json();
      setParseData(parseRes);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };

  const { email } = inputs;

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className='wrapper fadeInDown formAdjustmentLoginPage'>
        <div id='formContent'>
          <div className='fadeIn first'></div>
          <form className='formFunctions' onSubmit={onSubmitForm}>
            <input
              type='email'
              id='email'
              className='fadeIn second'
              name='email'
              placeholder='Email'
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
            />
            <button type='submit' className='fadeIn fourth'>
              Submit
            </button>
            <h1>{parseData}</h1> //I want to pass this to another component.
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
export default VerifyUser;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this.

Lets take a look at the simplest one - `state/props drilling`.

Say you have 2 components - `A` and `B` in such relation that `A` is a parent to `B`.

If you want to pass data from `A` to `B`, you simply pass it through `props`. If you want to pass data from `B` to `A` however, you need to pass a `set method` as a property and then call that `set method` from `B` to set the state of `A`:

```
const A = props => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({})

    return <B setData={setData} />
}

const B = props => {
    return (<button onClick={props.setData("Data")}>Set Data!</button>)
}
```

If you have a more complex structure, you try to find the closest common parent (component which parents both `A` and `B`). This however goes only so far, at some point it becomes impossible to maintain and costly to perform, so you will need to apply some sort of `global state management` tool. `Redux` is the most popular choice, but `Context API` is easier to learn.

Comment: Thank you so much!! it worked!! Yes I will learn Redux now.

Comment: I have one more question, how would I redirect to that component route along with data.

Comment: If you are using `react-router-dom` you can use the <Redirect /> component which re-routes the user. As for passing the data, there is not way of doing that through the route unless it is a small amount of data which can be passed as a route param. You can try to play around with local storage but in my experience that is very dependent on the scenario (keep in mind, local storage is not a part of the application state so a re-render will not be triggered when local storage changes)

Comment: Ok I understand. I will have to use redux for that I guess or Context API.